# Joomla 2.5+ language file editor

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am looking for a Joomla 2.5+ component to edit the language files (ex: languages/en_GB/en_GB.ini).

Changes have to be made *from the administrator*. We know we can edit the underlying files, but that will require change management in our production environment, with all the associated redtape.

I have tried searching for a solution on Google but didn't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need for Joomla! 2.5 the functionality already exists.

In Joomla! 2.5+ you can use the built-in language overrides editor. Simply select `Extensions->Language Manager->Overrides` and click the "**New**" button.

The nice thing about doing it this way is that you can safely apply Joomla! core updates without losing the overrides you've added.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one.  You'll need to edit the language files directly through FTP.

Fortunately, I've found [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.2.html) to be really good at this.  You can find details on the syntax of language files work [in the docs.](http://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files)

Comment: Thanks. We're trying to avoid updating files directly, but will go that route if needed.

Comment: You don't need to edit the files theres a built-in language override feature.